# Обновление загрузчика после замены материнской платы (BIOS to EFI)

Tags: grub, bios, fedora, uefi

Есть проблемы после замены материнской платы. Старая была с BIOS , а эта с EFI. После процедуры все работало, но только глючила клава в GRUB. Сделал `grub2-install и grub2-mkconfig`
и система вообще перестала грузиться. Тогда установил ещё одна на другой ЖД и после операций
`grub2-install и grub2-mkconfig`  могу загрузить и старую.

Я так понимаю, для нормальной работы нужен раздел /boot/EFI типа **EFI System**, но на настарой установке его и не было. Как полностью перенести загрузчик на этот ЖД? Почему-то грузится 29 версия, неизвестно откуда.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface

Comment: Из-за того, что загружено 29 ядро, а вся система 32 не могу ничего сделать. Даже не могу монтировать новый раздел с EFI

Comment: @dIm0n, удалось запустить линукс, но ГРУБ упорно не видит Виндовс 7. Можно что-то сделать, или все-таки придется переустанавливать систему?

Comment: По ссылке решения не помогли?

Comment: @dIm0n по ссылке вроде решения для Arch, а у меня Fedora https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2 Вот это помогло, но потом ни grub2-mkconfig ни os-probe не видят виндовс. По ссылке вроде тоже ничего такого нету

Comment: Большая часть статьи описывает настройку uefi в целом, безотносительно дистрибутива. Есть также про дуалбут с виндой

Comment: @dIm0n, читал статьи с ручной пропиской в конфиг. Но дело в том, что если добавить /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootx64.efi как прописано, то и федора не грузиться, ошибка ГРУБ